# check all values in table or object

Tags: php

i would like make somethings:

```
<?php 
$a = array();
for ($i =0; $i<15; $i++){
 $a[$i] = '111';
}

foreach ($a as $ok){
 //if all values in $a == 111 : {
echo "all is 111"
} else {
echo "no";
}
}

?>
```

LIVE: http://codepad.org/RdvhK0VD

is function in PHP for this? i must each values check separately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php 
    $a = array();
    for ($i =0; $i<15; $i++)
    {
        $a[$i] = '111';
    }
    $flag=true;
    foreach ($a as $ok)
    {
        if ( $a != 111 )
        {
            $flat=true;
        }
    }
    if(flag===true)
    {
        echo "all is 111"
    } else {
        echo "no";
    }
?>
```

Comment: This doesn't answer OP's question. OP was asking if there's a way to check this without manually iterating through the entire array.

Answer (score 3):

You can use **[array_count_values](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php)** which will return an associative array of values and their frequencies.

If `array_count_values($a)` returns an array of length 1 and its key is '111', then `$a` contains only '111'.

```
$arr2 = array_count_values($a);
$key = '111';

if( count($arr2) == 1 && array_key_exists($key, $a) )
{
  // $a contains only $key
}
```